# What does a null mean in React createElement()?

Tags: reactjs

```
return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name);
```

What does a `null` mean in React the above createElement() execution?

Answer (score 11):

```
React.createElement(type, props, children);
```

The props parameter is a JavaScript object passed from a parent element to a child element.
When you say `null` means you are not passing any props to that component.

~~

`type`  in `React.createElement` can be a string like `h1`, `div` etc or a React-Component.

`var reactElement = React.createElement('div', { className: 'header' });`

In this particular case when you pass prop `{ className: 'header' }` ,  created`div` element will have cssClass associated with it.

Comment: What is the 4th parameter "this.props.name". Does it gets merged with "Hello" String? The documentation mentions only 3 parameter type, props, children. I looked through the documentation but did not find any explanation.

Comment: @Niraj All parameters after props are [rested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) as children.

Answer (score 2):

The null is React.createElement is reserved for giving attribute values to the element. If you have none to pass then you put in a null, else you pass the attribute in a javascript object form. See example below. Here className is used for class as that is what is used in jsx to define html class.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', { className: "App" }, React.createElement('h1', null,'Title'));
  }
}

export default App;
```

This example outputs `<div class="App"><h1>Title</h1></div>`

Answer (score 1):

### It's just a null.

It means that the function waiting for some parameters. The second parameter is null so function know that it's null coming in if you don't pass null as second then your third parameter will be second and function will treat your third argument as second and things will goes wrong. There is for sure you can pass something else then null but I don't know that. [Read here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html)